# Ruby on Rails param is missing or the value is empty without using a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, param

In my contact.html, I have this code

```
            <div class="form">
                <form name="email-form" method="POST">
                    <label class="field-label" for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input class="w-input text-field-2" id="name" type="text" name="name" data-name="Name" required="required">
                    <label class="field-label" for="Email">Email:</label>
                    <input class="w-input text-field-2" id="email" type="email" name="email" data-name="Email" required="required">
                    <label class="field-label" for="Subject">Subject:</label>
                    <input class="w-input text-field-2" id="subject" type="text" name="subject" data-name="Subject">
                    <label class="field-label" for="Content">Text Message:</label>
                    <textarea class="w-input text-field-2 area" id="content" name="content" data-name="Text Area" required="required"></textarea>
                    <div>
                        <input class="w-button button" type="submit" value="Submit Message" data-wait="Please wait...">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

This is under my controller

```
 def contact

 end

 def send_mail
    MessageMailer.new_message(contact_params).deliver
    redirect_to contact_path, notice: 'Your messages has been sent.'
 end

 private
   def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :subject, :content)
   end
```

under mailers/message_mailer.rb

```
class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base
   default from: "sys.questdentalusa@gmail.com"
   default to: "questdentalusa@gmail.com"

   def new_message(contact)
      @contact = contact

      mail subject: @contact.subject
   end
end
```

and under my new_message.text.erb is this code

```
Name: <%= @contact.name %>
Email: <%= @contact.email %>
Message: <%= @contact.content %>
```

I am to send an email consisting user's name, email and message which is inputed and **NOT** saved in the database. When I pass the four parameters like this

```
def send_mail
    MessageMailer.new_message(:name, :email, :subject, :content).deliver
    redirect_to contact_path, notice: 'Your messages has been sent.'
end
```

it worked just fine but i was told to use only one parameter, seems like group the four parameters: `name, email, subject, content` as one (`contact`)

When I typed the info and hit the submit button, I get this error message
`param is missing or the value is empty: contact`
I presume that what caused this error is because my `def contact` is empty. So I added `contact.new` and `@contact=contact.new` and `MessageMailer.new` but this error occurs `NoMethodError`

How can I possibly fix this? What should I write under my `def contact` ?

Comment: contact.new doesn't work, it will be Contact.new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller code is correct. You don't need `Contact.new` or something. The problem is with your `<form>`. What ends up in `params` depends on your form and in your form you don't have `contact`.

Instead of:

```
<input type="text" name="subject">
```

You have to do something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="contact[subject]">
```

And that for all the fields on your contact form.

Another option would be to use Rails' form helpers.

Comment: Ah yes, this is a possibility too :)

Answer (score 1):

`contact[]` is missing in your form, see below correct one:

```
        <div class="form">
            <form name="email-form" method="POST">
                <label class="field-label" for="name">Name:</label>
                <input class="w-input text-field-2" id="name" type="text" name="contact[name]" data-name="Name" required="required">
                <label class="field-label" for="Email">Email:</label>
                <input class="w-input text-field-2" id="email" type="email" name="contact[email]" data-name="Email" required="required">
                <label class="field-label" for="Subject">Subject:</label>
                <input class="w-input text-field-2" id="subject" type="text" name="contact[subject]" data-name="Subject">
                <label class="field-label" for="Content">Text Message:</label>
                <textarea class="w-input text-field-2 area" id="content" name="contact[content]" data-name="Text Area" required="required"></textarea>
                <div>
                    <input class="w-button button" type="submit" value="Submit Message" data-wait="Please wait...">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: i havnt' seen, stackoverflow doesn't reload the page to see it, I was preparing/formatting my answer